# Acid hydrolysis of ethyl acetate

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrolysis, esters

For my chemistry IA, I am planning to determine the reaction rate and activation energy of the acid catalyzed hydrolysis of ethyl acetate. Where can I find literature values for these, so i can compare my results and evaluate my erros?

Comment: [hydrolysis of ethyl acetate](https://www.google.com/search?q=hydrolysis+of+ethyl+acetate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this 1953 article from ACS on this exact reaction: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01103a521

Does a variety of systems and calculates rate constants for comparison. I'd then recommend using similar terms they use to locate further resources on particular molecule hydrolysis, and even Google Scholar's (or Web of Science, Scopus, JSTOR, etc...) "cited by" option to work your way forward in time to papers that deal with this type of work. Using search terms from any articles you come across in databases (ACS, ScienceDirect, Scifinder, etc...) should get you going with plenty of benchmarking material as well.